# Zend  Form_element inside or appended to html tags containing text

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-decorators, html

In Zend_Form is it possible to prepend an element with a pair of html tags containing text using decorators?How?

Ex:

```
<div>My text inside html tags prepended..</div><input type='text'>
```

**EDITED:**

And what if I want to place a form element in a pair of html tags still containing text?

Ex.

```
<div>
 This div is containing both my custom text and my form element: 
 <input type='text'>
</div>
```

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
 $element->setDescription("My text");
```

You can also use a label if you want.

If you need you can use HtmlTag helper to be used by your decorator also, and set the position to be PREPEND.

## Edit

```
$elementDecorators = array(
                                'ViewHelper',
                                array('Label', array( 'tag' => 'span', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
                                array('Description', array( 'tag' => 'div', 'placement' => 'append','class'=>'eDesc')),                                
                                array('HtmlTag', array( 'tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'userElement'))
);

$element->setDecorators( $elementDecorators);
```

Comment: Updated with some sample options you can add.